# find and plot locations of minimum pixel intensity in each column

Tags: matlab, plot, pixel

i have a gray scale image. i would like to scan column by column to find the location of the darkest pixel in each column, obtain the (x,y) locations and plot a mark on it. the output of the prog should be an image with marks on each column's darkest pixel.

my attempt resulted in no output at all. please help me.

```
[row col] =size(i11);
for j=1:col
    for i=1:row
        darkestPixelValue = min(i11(i,j));    
        [i,j]=find(i11==darkestPixelValue);
        plot (i,j);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second output argument of `min`:

```
>> [mn row] = min( i11, [], 1 );
>> figure; imshow( i11 ); hold on; scatter( 1:size(i11,2), row, 40, 'xr' );
```

Comment: hi. i've tried the prog. but i get several plotted points on a straight line (left image) instead of a horizontal line (right image which i used Paint to show what is the desired output).

![Image Link](http://s13.postimg.org/h4a5l7ioz/Untitled.jpg).

Comment: @user2805487 - my bad: I mixed the arguments of `scatter` (confused x-y with row column). I edited my answer, please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to mark dark and light pixel column-wise, inspired from above (@shai and @user2805487):

```
    [r c]=size(a);
    pv=zeros(r,1);
    dark=zeros(c,1);
    for i=1:c
        for j=1:r
            pv(j)=a(j,i);
        end
    [ind dp] =min(pv);
    dark(i)=ind;
    [ind dp] =max(pv);
    lyt(i)=ind;
    end

    figure; imshow(a); hold on; scatter(1:c, dark, 40, 'xr' );
    figure; imshow(a); hold on; scatter(1:c, lyt, 40, 'xg' );
```